# How to use fancyhdr and appendixnumberbeamer in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am trying to use fancyhdr and appendixnumberbeamer in one tex file, but it seems like appendixnumberbeamer is disabled when fancyhdr is used. I am wondering if there's anyway I can use both.

My code is pasted below:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{graphicx,pgfpages,epsfig,multirow,lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{ulem}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %???
\pagestyle{fancy} %???
\fancypagestyle{plain} %???
\fancyhf{} %???
\fancyfoot[C]{\raisebox{5pt}{\tiny\thepage\//\pageref{LastPage}}} %???
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %???
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} %???
\setcounter{page}{0} %???

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}


\mode<presentation> {
   %\usetheme{Singapore}
   %\usecolortheme{kurt}
   %\usecolortheme{kurthandout}
   \useoutertheme[footline=authortitle, subsection=false]{miniframes}
   %\setbeamercovered{invisible}
   \setbeamercovered{invisible}
   \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % no navigation icons
   \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]

Include wallpaper here using ThisCenterWallPaper{1}{wallpage.pdf} 

\end{frame}


\section{Overview}
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}{Section 1}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Section 2}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\includepdf[pagecommand={\pagestyle{fancy}}]{slides_pdf/somepdf.pdf}
\end{frame}

 \appendix
%------------------------------------------------
\section{Appendix A}
%------------------------------------------------
\subsection{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{}
Appendix blah
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I comment out the fancy part (lines with questions marks), appendixnumberbeamer will work, but my pdf is messed up..

Ideally I would like to see:
[image: with the top, but with includepdf image]

but with pdfs.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: don't use fancyhdr with beamer. How do you want your footline to look like?

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` or `color` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality. And please don't load the same package multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `fancyhdr` with beamer - beamer provides its own mechanism to customise the footline. From `\fancyfoot` I guess you want to add page numbers in the centre of the footline? You can do this by modifying the footline definition.

The purpose of `\includepdf` is to include whole pages, therefore don't use it inside a frame. If you want to include a pdf inside of a frame, use `\includegraphics[page=3,width=\textwidth]{example-image-a4-numbered}` instead.

---

Some additional suggestions:

- instead of the page number, I would use the frame number, otherwise you will count every single overlay
- please don't load packages more than once.
- you don't need `graphicx` or `color` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality

---

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}

\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle, subsection=false]{miniframes}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
    leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}%
    \hfill%
    {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\insertframenumber{}\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber}%
    \hfill%
    {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\author{names}
\title{text}

\begin{document}

\section{Overview}
\begin{frame}{Section 1}
    test
\end{frame}

{
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=} 
  \includepdf[pages=1]{example-image.pdf}    
}

\appendix
\section{Appendix A}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
    Appendix blah
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```